# Linearity conditions, why do we need Additivity?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, linear-transformations

TLDR;
Why do we need the additivity condition to capture the linearity of a function?

---

In Linear Algebra, it is stated that a function is considered a linear map if it satisfies two conditions:

1. Additivity: $f(x + y) = f(x) + f(y)$
2. Homogeneity: $f(cx) = cf(x)$

Now I sort of get why we need the homogeneity condition to preserve ratios/proportionality.

I cannot seem to easily see what additivity has to do with it. Maybe the question boils down to capturing the *essence* of what we mean by *linear*?

I tried dropping the additivity condition, but I couldn't easily come up with a "nice" function that is homogeneous but not additive. At least not without using some "pathological" functions like ones defined by cases or tables?

Comment: The intuition I use is that linear transformations map lines to lines, so it preserves the structure of the vector space in some way. For example, try applying a linear transformation to a line $\vec x +t \vec d$ where $d$ is not in the kernel. You need the additivity of the function to conclude that it remains a line

Comment: A pathological function that is homogeneous and not additive is $f:\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R^2$, $f(x,y)=\begin{cases}e^{x^2/(x^2+y^2)}(x,y)&\text{if }x\ne 0\lor y\ne0\\ (0,0)&\text{if }x=y=0\end{cases}$. For a non-pathological example see the function $g(x,y)=e^{\int_0^x 2ty^2(t^2+y^2)^{-2}\,dt}(x,y)$.

Comment: Homogeneity alone only preserves the ratio along a line, i.e. along a fixed angle (mod $\pi$ and in regards to some fixed vector). So if you take a linear function and multiply it by a function that's dependent only on the angle you got a good chance to get a function that his homogeneous but not additive. One such example would be $f(x,y):=\frac{|x|}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}\cdot x$

Comment: @hff1 ahh that's the equation of a line in vector form for more than 2-dimensions right? I see where you're going with this. It reminds me of 3B1B's explanation about keeping lines parallel and the origin fixed.

This doesn't require any further functions to make it clear. Thank you

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio I am curious how you arrived at the $g(x, y)$ function if you don't mind expanding on it.

Comment: @Sudix I don't think I fully understand you. are you talking about lines in polar coordinates?

Comment: @IbrahimNajjar Any set of coordinates works. Polar coordinates have the advantage of isolating the angle as parameter(s), which makes the form of the angle-dependent-function  easier. In turn, checking additivity is more difficult. That's why the example I gave used regular coordinates. In it, the right factor $x$ is the linear function, and the left factor is $\cos(\angle(\binom {|x|}{ |y|},\binom 1 0))$. Here, $\binom 1 0$ is the fixed line I chose as reference for the angle, and $\angle$ is the angle between its two inputs (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product#Geometric_definition)

Answer (score 1):

The key point of both of these axioms for linearity is that function application *commutes with* (more accurately, preserves) the fundamental vector space operations.

Consider $f:A\rightarrow B$. $f(x+y)$ means "add $x$ and $y$ as $A$-vectors, then transform the result to a $B$-vector; linearity lets you do $f(x)+f(y)$ "transform $x$ and $y$ first, then add the results as $B$-vectors", and get the same answer.

This is the property that characterizes homomorphisms - maps between algebraic structures that respect the essential properties of the structure type - and in fact linear maps are nothing more than homomorphisms of vector spaces.

Comment: That's a different interesting perspective. I do remember coming across homomorphisms when I was studying group theory a bit. So linearity is not the only reason, preserving the structure is another right?

Comment: It's more fundamental - "linearity" of the function just means "linear map", which is the **name** for homomorphisms in the special case of vector spaces, if we take the category theory-level view. From this POV, the properties required of linearity are what it takes to preserve the algebraic structure of vector spaces, and can be mechanically derived.

Answer (score -2):

To build off of @hff1's comment, consider the function $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ given by $f(x,y) = (x,|y|)$. This has homogeneity but not additivity. And consider what it does to the straight line $y=x$. It maps it to the "bent" line $y=|x|$. So, if you accept that a "linear transformation" of a straight line should be another straight line, you need additivity.

Comment: Your $f$ is homogeneous in the sense of satisfying $f(\lambda v)=\lambda f(v)$ for all $\lambda>0$, but it's manifestly not homogeneous in the sense of $f(\lambda v)=\lambda f(v)$ for all $\lambda\in\Bbb R$, which is what the OP most likely means.